# Spring oAuth2 with user rights

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I am very new to oauth and especially spring oauth2. In my project currently I am using basic spring oauth by enabling spring security provider through xml config.

Current configuration supports the access to my service using ROLE_CLIENT.
The db for that is just the reference db as specified in spring reference docs

[image]

But now I need to extend the spring security authorization in a user level with USER RIGHTS instead of ROLE based as spring default does.

Now I have the following tables
[image]

What is the way to use oauth2 and authorize my apis using user rights using spring security.

Here is my context securty.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

 
 <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
  authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <anonymous enabled="false" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
  <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
  <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request  parameters -->
  <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
  <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
 </http>

 <!--OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so 
  can deal with authorization and error handling separately -->
 <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <anonymous enabled="false" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT" requires-channel="https"/>
  <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
  <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
 </http>
 
 <bean id="clientDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
   <ref bean="dataSource" />
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
 
 <!-- Configure Authentication manager -->
 <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
  <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
  <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>
 <!-- Used for the persistence of tokens (currently an in memory implementation) 
 <bean id="tokenStore"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />
 -->
 <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
 
 <!-- Used to create token and every thing about them except for their persistence 
  that is reposibility of TokenStore -->
 <bean id="tokenServices"  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
  <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
  <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
  <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
  <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="4500" />
 </bean>
 <!-- <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler"> 
  <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" /> </bean> -->

 <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
  <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
  <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
  <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="realmName" value="Authorization" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="realmName" value="Authorization/client" />
  <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

 <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
  <constructor-arg>
   <list>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
   </list>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

 <!--  
 <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
 </authentication-manager>
 
 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <authentication-provider>
   <user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <user name="user" password="user123" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />
   </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
 -->
 
 <authentication-manager alias="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
   <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
 
 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
  <authentication-provider>
      <!--  password-encoder hash="sha" />-->
      <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
   <jdbc-user-service  data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
  </authentication-provider>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
 </authentication-manager>

 
 <!--AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface that defines everything 
  necessary for token management -->
 <oauth:authorization-server 
     client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
     token-services-ref="tokenServices"
  user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
  <oauth:authorization-code />
  <oauth:implicit />
  <oauth:refresh-token />
  <oauth:client-credentials />
  <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
 </oauth:authorization-server>

 <oauth:resource-server 
     id="resourceServerFilter" 
     resource-id="rest_api" 
     token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

 <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
  <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
   http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
  <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
 </sec:global-method-security>
 <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
 <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your userDetails class add method that checks for given RIGHT and then in your

```
   <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT" requires-channel="https"/>
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

instead of

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT" requires-channel="https"/>
```

use

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="getPrincipal().hasHasSpecificRight()" requires-channel="https"/>
```

where `hasHasSpecificRight()` is the method checking for the required RIGHT

Comment: I couldnt find such a function available in principal.. Then how I am supposed to write the EL for that call.

Comment: You could not because I said above that you have to Implement your own `clientDetails`. Can you tell me what class type your `getPrincipal()` method returns, it wil be easier to point you in the right direction? http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user

Comment: I am using the oauth as explained in the spring reference doc. and my db is as same as the spring reference(the first image shows the relations). And I am using JdbcClientDetailsService as the clientDetails.

Comment: I see what you are using but can you tell me what type of object your getPrincipal() returns? You will be authenticating against the property of the authenticated user ,  user has RIGHTS and you have to check what rights this user has in order to see if he is authorized, but you have to find the way to access the object that allows you to do the checking. If you post what class your getPrincipal() returns we can start from there. It is not just one line of code problem.

Comment: This is the Principal Object  Type : org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication

Here is the contents inside it: 
Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT

Comment: read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html  you will have to implement your own `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl` and make sure that it reads your RIGHTS into your `userDetails` implemantation beacuse so far you are using this <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" /> and it is very basic and only reads username and pasword and authorities table so your RIGHTs are never even read for the present user and it is not authentication problem but rather loading the user properly

Comment: also If I were you I would just use regular Spring repository interfaces and implement my own `UserDetailsService` , you can find dozen of examples on the web how to do that so I will not post it here,  when you load you user details properly containing set of your RIGHTS then you can check agains it in your `access="getPrincipal().hasHasSpecificRight()"` as I stated above because getPrincipal() returns exacly the userDetails that you loaded from the database including your rights, but its your custom `UserDetails` implemantation that has to contain the method that provides acces to RIGHTS

Comment: Thanks alot...i will try to implement one myself

Comment: When I add strings like permitAll or getPrincipal().hasHasSpecificRight() I am getting error saying this all are not supported. What could be the reason